# mvc: Using the same webgrid for data display on the click of a button when index page is already loaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have code below that pulls data from a database, returns a viewmodel and populates a webgrid.
 On the view, there is a dropdownlist and a button beside it.

I will want my users to select any item from the dropdown list and click on the button to search
 for data using the item selected.

I want to reuse the webgrid to display the data. I am thinking I need to make an Ajax call on the click of
 the button.

How do i do this so that I can use the webgrid again.

```
         public ActionResult Index()
                {
                    string phyLocationName = string.Empty;
                    string extractPhylocationcode = string.Empty;
                    var currentUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
                    Edmviewmodel objedmtest = new Edmviewmodel();

                    if (currentUser != null)
                    {              
                        try
                        {
                            string cleanedCurrentUser = currentUser.Substring(5);
                            SearchActiveDirectory obj = new SearchActiveDirectory();
                            phyLocationName = obj.GetLocationCode(cleanedCurrentUser);
                            extractPhylocationcode = phyLocationName.Substring(0, 3);

                            //Use my viewmodel to get all data                  
                            objedmtest = _edmDataService.GetRequiredData(extractPhylocationcode);
                            objedmtest.BranchesSetup.selectedbranch = phyLocationName;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            //logger.Error(ex);
                        }
                    }

                    return View(objedmtest);
                }
```

I have the data I need for the webgrid in my viewmodel already which is this line below. So do i need another one?

```
            public List<Catalogorder> GetCatDataByLocation { get; set; }

            public class Edmviewmodel
            {
               public Setupbranches BranchesSetup { get; set; }
               public List<Catalogorder> GetCatDataByLocation { get; set; }
               public List<SelectListItem> GetRouteByBranch { get; set; }

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a framework of how you can achieve this with some code reuse (not having to duplicate your code to render the grid)

Edmviewmodel

```
List<WebgridItems> Items { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
Index()
    Get the Items and build the Edmviewmodel
    View(Edmviewmodel)
```

View

```
@model Edmviewmodel

Html.PartialView("Grid", Edmviewmodel.Items)
```

Grid Partial View

```
@model List<WebgridItems>

foreach(var item in Model)
    render grid row
```

Now for the Ajax call

Controller

```
IndexGrid(int filterItem)
    var vm = Get the List<WebgridItems> using the filterItem
    return PartialView("Grid, vm)
```

Client-side
When a dropdown item is selected and the button is clicked, call the `IndexGrid` with the filterItem. Replace the grid with the resulting HTML.

Comment: Thanks. Am not very clear about this. I need to create a partial view right?

Comment: Yes, that's what will be responsible for rendering the grid so the model for it is just the list of items. It will be used by the Index view and when making an ajax call.

Comment: I added my viewmodel which I have.